# toggleClass does not work on hover as expected - won´t resize div

Tags: jquery, html, css

My goal is to change the css class of a div on hover, which does not work accurately. (Change smoothly from lsausschreibung to resizels). The code aims at displaying two different sized boxes next to each other, which will swop sizes on hover of the smaller box.

Any hints are highly appreciated!

```js
$("rsausschreibung").hover(function() {
  $("lsausschreibung").toggleClass("resizels");
});
```

```css
.annonce {
  margin-left: 30px; 
  width: auto;
}

.lsausschreibung {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -10px;
  height: 320px;
  width: 280px; 
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
}

.resizels {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 290px; 
  width: 230px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.rsausschreibung {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 290px; 
  width: 230px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.rsausschreibung:hover {
  z-index: 20;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 320px;
  width: 280px;
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="annonce">

  <div class="lsausschreibung">

  </div>

  <div class="rsausschreibung">

  </div>
```

Comment: Should your transition css be more like `transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out` ?

Comment: Did unfortunately not help... but thanks for your advice

Comment: @JonathanHamel The 0 in front of the decimal does not (or should not) affect the functionality of the code. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FN55NDZHDPC5) for example. (Click run to see the result of the code)

Comment: Support for `.hover()` pseudo function has been removed in more recent versions of jQuery. Try `$("rsausschreibung").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("resizels");
    });` instead. For a smooth transition you need to add the transition rule by @JonathanHamel, too. Also, you are mixing jQuery hover functionality with CSS:hover, why are you doing that? You should not be using jQuery for this at all.

Comment: @JonathanHamel I hope you understand everything when you see the snippet.

Comment: @connexo I don't see anything about `.hover()` being removed in the jQuery documentation. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: You're missing the `.` in the jQuery selectors, so the code is never being run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about something like that ?

```js
$(".rsausschreibung").hover(function() {
  $(".lsausschreibung").toggleClass("small large");
  $(".rsausschreibung").toggleClass("small large");
});
```

```css
.annonce {
  margin-left: 30px; 
  width: auto;
}

.lsausschreibung {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -10px;   
  background-color: white;    
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.large {
  height: 320px;
  width: 280px; 
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); 
}

.small {
  height: 290px; 
  width: 230px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.rsausschreibung {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="annonce">
    <div class="lsausschreibung large">
    </div>
    <div class="rsausschreibung small">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @connexo Got a better way?

Comment: I am currently looking for a solution which aims at creating several of these boxes with this hover effect. The easiest solution would be to duplicate the code each time and change the id. Now I am looking for a better and more lean solution to achieve several duplications of the example shown in the snippet.

Comment: Why duplicating the code? You can extract the functionality to a function and reuse this function in multiple places. Also, I suggest using classes instead of IDs so they don't have to be unique in your html.